# Using large tables doesn't seem to work in Blazor WASM

Tags: itext7, blazor-webassembly

In a Blazor WASM application (.NET 5), I have a Razor component where I'm creating a table with roughly 4k rows, and following the tutorial from the iText website found [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2#Chapter5:AddingAbstractElementobjects(part2)-Tablesandmemoryuse).

```
var dataTable = new Table(5, true)
  .UseAllAvailableWidth()
  .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
dataTable.AddColumnHeader("Header 1");
dataTable.AddColumnHeader("Header 2");
dataTable.AddColumnHeader("Header 3");
dataTable.AddColumnHeader("Header 4");
dataTable.AddColumnHeader("Header 5");
document.Add(dataTable);
    
for (int i = 0; i < FilteredItems.Count; i++)
{
  var item = FilteredItems.ElementAt(i);
  dataTable.AddColumnData(item.Item1);
  dataTable.AddColumnData(item.Item2);
  dataTable.AddColumnData(item.Item3);
  dataTable.AddColumnData(item.Item4);
  dataTable.AddColumnData(item.Item5);

  if (i % 50 == 0)
  {
    dataTable.Flush();
  }
}

dataTable.Complete();
document.Close();
```

I get the following error for what looks like every flush `Error: Garbage collector could not allocate 16384u bytes of memory for major heap section.`

I suspect this may be a Blazor limitation. Anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Already tried with .net 6 preview? Don't think that this will work but give it a tried - it's a mono error.
Why no paging for the dataTable data? On which screen you could show 4k table rows? No need to load all in one table.

Comment: There's no paging because we are storing everything client-side in indexeddb, so its no problem loading everything into the table, its just printing it that is the issue. We made a workaround of limiting the amount of records that can be printed. We'll come back to it at a later time to try .NET 6. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

- Low lantency for much RAM
- No Low latency for small RAM

therefore:

**Turn off low latency.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/latency?redirectedfrom=MSDN

in `app.config`

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="false" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```